# android studio - gradle manifest file path

Tags: android, gradle

I was trying to add the v4 support library in Android Studio.

My build.gradle lookes like this so far :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
  }
}

allprojects {

  apply plugin: 'android'

  android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"        
  }

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
  }
}
```

It started giving me the error (my project name is DataSharing-1):

```
AndroidStudioProjects/DataSharing-1/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

I tried adding the following under 'android {' :

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'DataSharing-1/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
```

I get the error :

```
DataSharing-1/app/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

If I change the srcFile to

```
'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

I get the error :

```
DataSharing-1/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

My folder structure is :

```
AndroidStudioProjects/DataSharing-1/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Can someone suggest on how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to add the support library to your project:

1. Open build.gradle (the one with the `android` and `dependencies` element).
2. Under `dependencies` add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'`

It should look as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    //... your previous existing dependencies after here
}
```

You can replace the `+` symbol with a specific version, but the `+` symbol is preferable since it ensures you will get the latest version of the library.

Comment: Thanks. Gradle sync worked. But it says : support library should not use a lower version (18) that target SDK version (19)

Comment: Okay. I changed it to : compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'