# error - "Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag" after importing eclipse project to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

After importing my java eclipse project into android studio I came across errors when trying to run my android app. I am using Android Studio 3.1, and Gradle  4.1

In the "Edit Configurations" window, it says "Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"

[image]

I don't have a manifest file or a res file which is not normal and I know that my project requires an android Manifest file to function properly, Did I import the eclipse project incorrectly?,

Here are images of the project directory,

[image]

[image]

Here is a side by side with a working android studio project

[side by side comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOkBk.jpg)

I have tried syncing project with gradle files and invalidated the projects caches, neither worked.

Also If I start a new Android Studio Project and use a preset activity (e.g Google Maps Activity), everything works fine, so I think I must have made a mistake when importing but have tried re-importing and used multiple versions of Android Studio but have had no luck.

Comment: Errrors should be included as text in the body of the question. But where is the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: The only place i can find it is in the libraries folder under packages.

Comment: Create a brand new Android project using the the IDE and inspect how all the necessary files are created for you. Compare with what you have. No one can figure this out with the screenshots you provide.

Comment: The new android studio project has: a manifests folder, java folder, and a res folder, along with gradle scripts,  whereas my project just has the java folder with gradle scripts

Comment: It sounds like the import was not successful or was incomplete. You need to determine if the manifest is being found at all (possibly via code or properties in the Gradle config) or it is being found but is malformed. See https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html as well as hints in questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110503/1531971

Comment: Can i create my own AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Of course. See that link. It is literally a well-formed XML file using a specific schema. I my experience it isn't worth importing Eclipse projects. Create a project and then import the source into the right places and tune from there.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help